# how to resolve detail query in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'Relationtable.Controllers.MoviesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: add your code and know the posting rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Make your parameter "ID" nullable. (It is inside your model).

Look into the [Nullable](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/05/27/143221.aspx) value type.